# chamar uma tela com apenas botões e metodos

Tags: java, android

Eu preciso criar uma tela que chame outra, porem quero fazer isso usando apenas metodos, e no codigo que fiz ela não ta chamando a outra.

Na primeira tela eu tenho uma lista e um botão incluir. Quando clicar no botão incluir, tem que aparecer outra tela para digitar o nome, ai eu clico no botão ok incluir e ela volta para a primeira tela com as listas mostrando o novo contato adiciona.

```
package com.example.pamelaelias.contatos;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lista;
    List lista2 = new ArrayList();
    Button btnIncluir, btnOkIncluir;
    EditText txtNome;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idLista);
        lista2.add("Pamela");
        lista2.add("Brenda");
        lista2.add("Gabriel");
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adp = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista2);
        lista.setAdapter(adp);
    }
    public void TelaInicial() {
        btnIncluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.incluir);
                btnOkIncluir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOkIncluir);
                txtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
                Incluir();
            }
        });
    }

    public void Incluir() {
         final ArrayAdapter<String> st = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista2);
        btnOkIncluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                btnIncluir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIncluir);
                lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idLista);
                lista2.add(txtNome.getText());
                lista.setAdapter(st);
                TelaInicial();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html?hl=pt-br

Comment: Sinceramente não entendi quase nada do que você explicou, foi até dificil editar por isso. Sugiro que edite a pergunta, e explique melhor o que quer fazer, está bem confuso entender seu texto.,

Comment: kkkkkkk ai mds nem sei como explicar por aqui, é assim.. eu preciso fazer uma tela que tenha um botao chamado incluir e uma lista, quando clicar nesse botão 'incluir' ele vai para outra tela que tem um outro botão chamado 'ok incluir' onde eu vou digitar um nome e quando eu clicar neste botão 'ok incluir' ele volta para a primeira tela mostrando a lista com o novo nome adicionado.

Answer (score 0):

deixa eu ver se entendi sua duvida...

voce não quer criar outra activity mas sim mudar o layout da atual sem precisar de outras classes?

De qualquer forma no OnCreate voce não setou nenhuma acao para os botoes entao mesmo voce tendo criado os metodos o botao não vai fazer nada(a nao ser que voce tenha vinculado o metodo via xml)

Se realmente quiser fazer desta forma utilize o codigo abaixo:

```
package com.example.pamelaelias.contatos;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView lista;
    List lista2;
    Button btnIncluir;
    Button btnOkIncluir;
    EditText txtNome;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        lista2 = new ArrayList();
        lista2.add("Pamela");
        lista2.add("Brenda");
        lista2.add("Gabriel");
        carregaPrimeiraTela();
    }

    private void carregaPrimeiraTela(){
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnIncluir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIncluir);
        btnIncluir.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                carregaSegundaTela();
            }
        });
        atualisaLista();
    }

    private void carregaSegundaTela(){
        setContentView(R.layout.incluir);
        btnOkIncluir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOkIncluir);
        btnOkIncluir.setOnClickListener(acaoBtnOkIncluir());
        txtNome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
    }

    private void atualisaLista() {
        lista = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.idLista);
        ArrayAdapter adp = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, lista2);
        lista.setAdapter(adp);
    }

    public View.OnClickListener acaoBtnOkIncluir() {
        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                btnIncluir = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnIncluir);
                lista2.add(txtNome.getText());
                atualisaLista();
                carregaPrimeiraTela();
            }
        };
    }
}
```